# the releative path in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I meet some problem when locate the resources such as css js img in the page.

For example,I want to use a javascript lib:dtree,it contain some built-in images and css.

This is its structure:

```
img
dtree.css
dtree.js
example.html
```

The exmaple.html is a live demo to show how to use dtree. It use the dtree.js as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dtree.js"></script>
```

Now I create a new folder,and copy the example.html here,and modify the src of the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dtree.js"></script>
```

Now,this is the new structure:

```
img
dtree.css
dtree.js
example.html
chd
--example.html
```

When I browser the chd/example.html,some required imgs are missing.

And in the dtree.js,there are some codes like:

```
this.icon = {
  root:'img/base.gif',
  ....
}
```

So I think the img here are not based on the dtree.js but the current page which call the js.

If so,I think I am fxxked.

I have to put all my pages to the same  directory with the img(it contains the required imgs by dtree.js) if I want to use the dtree.js?

And solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to adjust image root path by adding slash before img like:

```
this.icon = {
  root:'/img/base.gif',
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,now I want to know who does the /img/base.gis based?  the js file or the html page calling the js?

Comment: @hguser: I did'nt understand your question fully, but I think above code is in your js file.

Comment: in the js the path is "img/base.gif". If the html is put under the chd folder,/chd/example.html,so how does it find the base.gif?  is it /chd/img/base.gif or img/base.gif?

Comment: it should be just /img/base.gif

Comment: But the real path should be ../img/base.gif,so if I want the /chd/example.html work,I have to modify the .js,but if so the /example.html can not work. it seems that the only way is setting the path start with "/" (absolute path),right?

Comment: /img/base.gif means path related to root no matter you add this js from any of the folder it will look for image file (base.gif in this case) from the root. if you use ../img or img you will always have to change path accordingly when u move html files from one folder to another